# How to post array data in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

i want to crop image using  jQuery Guillotine Plugin in my codeigniter project. i just dont know how to post data `var data = picture.guillotine('getData');// { scale: 1.4, angle: 270, x: 10, y: 20, w: 400, h: 300 }` to my controller.
i have tried using html post

the view code :

```
  var datacrop = picture.guillotine('getData');                   
  $('#datax').val(datacrop.x);
  $("#datay").val(datacrop.y);
  $("#dataw").val(datacrop.w);
  $("#datah").val(datacrop.h);
```

and

```
<input type="hidden" id="datax" name="x" value=""  />
<input type="hidden" id="datay" name="y" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="dataw" name="w" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="datah" name="h" value="" />
```

controller code :

```
$source = $this->input->post('gambar');
$x = $this->input->post('x');
$y=$this->input->post('y');
$w = $this->input->post('w');
$h=$this->input->post('h');
$h=$this->input->post('name');

$config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
$config['source_image'] = $source;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
$config['width']         = $w;
$config['height']         = $h;
$config['x_axis'] = '$x';
$config['y_axis'] = '$y';


$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
if ( ! $this->image_lib->crop()){
    $msg = $this->image_lib->display_errors('','');
    echo $msg;
}
else{
    redirect('banners/index');           
}
```

the problem is, when i change the scale, hidden input x and y still gave me 0. maybe there is a better way to posting array data

Comment: `'$x'` and `'$y'` will not resolved because you but them in single quote, they should be like this `"$x"` , `"$y"` or `$x`, `$y`

Comment: Add `var_dump($config);` and see the array is proper or not

Comment: @developer thank but it doesnt work.  if i give value directly to hidden input x and y, my controller could read it. maybe the problem is  when i load the page my jquerry  script  will give 0 value to hidden input, but when i change the scale, it is not change hidden input. i need kind of auto refresh  form to update hidden input value. or there is another way to post array data.